# How to create a feature vector to recognize characters using open cv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I'm new to image processing. My project is to recognize characters in vehicle number plates.(Automatic vehicle number plate detection). Therefore I need to extract features like number of lines in the character, number of holes, etc and create a  feature vector in open cv . As i'm new to this I have no idea. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **OpenALPR** library its is an open source Automatic License Plate Recognition library written in C++ with bindings in C#, Java, Node.js, Go, and Python. The library analyzes images and video streams to identify license plates. The output is the text representation of any license plate characters.

other link that would help you is like

1. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654620/how-to-detect-digits-from-license-plates-using-opencv-and-c)

another link

2. [enter link description here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10737/licence-plate-detection-with-different-backgrounds)

Comment: Thank You. I will look into this.